# esp32 crashing and rebooting

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I am attempting to import an Arduino project into ESP-IDF using Arduino as a component. However, when I try to run the code, I encounter the following error logs.

```
`�[0;32mI (1200) cam_hal: cam init ok�[0m
�[0;32mI (1200) sccb: pin_sda 26 pin_scl 27�[0m
�[0;31mE (1202) i2c: i2c driver install error�[0m
�[0;32mI (1214) camera: Detected camera at address=0x3c�[0m
�[0;31mE (1215) ledc: ledc_stop(661): LEDC is not initialized�[0m
�[0;31mE (1215) camera: Detected camera not supported.�[0m
�[0;31mE (1217) camera: Camera probe failed with error 0x106(ESP_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)�[0m
�[0;31mE (1221) ledc: ledc_stop(661): LEDC is not initialized�[0m
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d8ef4  PS      : 0x00060e30  A0      : 0x800d82e9  A1      : 0x3ffb21e0  
A2      : 0x00000106  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x000186a0  
A6      : 0x3ffc2d5c  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x800d8ef2  A9      : 0x3ffb21c0  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x000004c1  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x80000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000002  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffff9  


Backtrace: 0x400d8ef1:0x3ffb21e0 0x400d82e6:0x3ffb2220 0x400dc64a:0x3ffb2260 0x4008e199:0x3ffb2280



ELF file SHA256: 375623c71663f5ca

Rebooting...`
```

if you want any clarification just lemme know i'am stuck with this issue from past 2 weeks please kindly help me and this code in arduino works fine but when im porting it into esp idf these errors, please help me out

clear understanding of debugging this error and prompt response

Comment: Try using `addr2line` with your backtrace to see exactly where the crash is happening. `xtensa-esp32-elf-addr2line -pfiaC -e build/app.elf <list of addresses in the backtrace>`

Comment: can you elaborate how to add it i'm a newbie trying to port an Arduino ide project to ESP-IDF

Comment: hello, I have observed that when I comment out the camera functionality in my code, everything works properly. Therefore, it appears that the crash is specifically related to the camera integration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the LEDC initialization or might be after that there wouldbe some error that is not allowing to process on esp32, look for any loophole in that part, try to eleiminate that issue, then it will stop panicking. And it would be better if you share your code snippet with us, for better understanding.

Comment: Hello below link can give you an overveiw of problem i'm facing

https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/issues/565

still you want to see the code its actually very big one i can share it in private.

Comment: hello, I have observed that when I comment out the camera functionality in my code, everything works properly. Therefore, it appears that the crash is specifically related to the camera integration.

Comment: Hi, then it might be issue that camera is not supported for espidf, you can get some information about addition of camera driver in esp-idf using this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghyzmZ8iA7w